# Fivestar Field Not Showing

Tags: nodes, rating

I've enabled Fivestar and added it to the comments field and made sure its in the comment display as well.

I've allowed anonymous and other users the ability to use Fivestar in Permissions. I've changed comments permissions so users can leave them and see their own.

I've created a new content piece and flushed caches to check if it only provides the field on NEW items.

In firebug on FF it says the rating field is in there but for some reason it's not showing up on the screen. Here's the code from Firebug:

```
<div id="edit-field-rating" class="field-type-fivestar field-name-field-rating field-widget-exposed form-wrapper"></div>
```

Any idea what might be going on here or ways to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it'll will work if you change the Widget type on the Comment Fields tab to "Stars (rated while editing)". Give it a try.